# github no address associated with name

Tags: git, github

I kept having problem with github these days, i created a new repository on github, then from local machine I tried to push my code to github:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:tmi/logger.git
fatal: remote origin already exists

git push origin master
ssh: github.com:uhdyi: no address associated with name
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

ssh git -v
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Fed 2007
ssh: git: no address associated with name

ssh git@github.com
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Documents and Settings/tmi/.ssh/id_rsa':
Error: HI, tmi! you've successfullly authenticated, but GitHub doesn not provide shell access
connection to github.com closed

git push origin master
ssh: github.com:uhdyi: no address associated with name
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

what's wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Look:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists
```

You already have a remote named `origin`, and it's still using the old, invalid URL. Open up `.git/config` and change the URL for the `origin` remote, or use the `set-url` subcommand for `git remote`:

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:tmi/logger.git
```

Comment: `ssh: git: no address associated with name` and `fatal: remote origin already exists?` are two separate problems. What's the solution to the former one?

Comment: For me, `ssh: git: no address associated with name` happened because my internet connection was busted in a VM

Answer (score 5):

I had the no address associated with name problem and after searching it was a DNS problem.
The DNS simply was wrong on the machine and it could not find the IP address of the remote git repository.

Comment: Yes, I had this problem and I cleared my DNS cache. On Windows this is done from command prompt using ipconfig /flushdns

I was then able to run my git commands with no issues. So, lesson learned is that git bash still uses the local OS DNS resolvers.

Answer (score 4):

How would the error

```
ssh git -v
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Fed 2007
ssh: git: no address associated with name
```

be  related to

```
fatal: remote origin already exists?
```

Also couldn't that problem be solved by

```
git remote add someothername git@github.com:tmi/logger.git
```

Comment: `ssh: git: no address associated with name` and `fatal: remote origin already exists?` are indeed two separate problems and unfortunately mipadi answers only to the latter one.